# NavigationBar tint Color with Hex value does not work well in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar, background-color

If I am set `UIColor.Red` in the NavigationBar it is work Perfect.

**Code :**

```
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.Red;
this.NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = false;
```

**Output:**

[image]

But If i set `Hex color` it is display some other color not actual I want

```
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.Clear.FromHexString("#0072BA", 1.0f);
this.NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = false;
```

**Output :**

[image]

**Actual Output Color :**

[image]

> ## Note :
>
> I also set color using `FromRGB` but that also display different
>   color.

Is there any property I miss then tell me because I am new to Xamarin and Ios.

Any Help be Appreciated.

### Simple Question :

InBuild color work but why Hex Color code not work.

Comment: by the way you hex color code doesn't give expected output, do check that too.

Comment: @iphonic yes and i also check with `UIColor.FromRGB` but that also not work. You can simply see my display output and desire output.

Comment: One more way is there. Use color picker of storyboard or xib you can get 75 matching to color. Use tha tool to find RGB

Comment: @Vinodh Thnx your idea is helpful for me.

Comment: If you got desired output you can post it as answer so for others it will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the `Combine of My idea` and `@KKRocks Solution` now is work for me is below thing.

Use this code :

```
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(0,114,186);
this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Translucent = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable this property for naviagtionbar .

```
NavigationController.NavigationBar.Translucent = false;
```

Comment: did you try this?

Comment: Yes I have tried when you post the answer i will copy your line but that not work bro.

Comment: 1+ for something that help me.